# Generating all binary trees for k ordinals in R

Tags: r, binary-tree

Suppose that, given a list of ordinals in R, I want to generate all ordered binary trees as a recursive list of <=2 lists.

So, for example, given `list(2,1,4,3)`, the output would be:

```
list(list(1, list(2, list(3, 4))),
     list(1, list(list(2, 3), 4)),
     list(list(1, 2), list(3, 4)),
     list(list(1, list(2, 3)), 4),
     list(list(list(1, 2), 3), 4))
```

The order in which the trees are listed doesn't really matter.  Sorting isn't a problem, but I'm struggling a lot with making a working functional recursion.  I know R is pretty slow with recursion, but speed here isn't an issue, as I'm dealing with lists of fairly low (<=7) order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should get you going. It takes whatever list you give it and outputs all binary trees keeping the items in the list in the order they were given:

```
trees <- function(l) {
    if (length(l) <= 1)
        return(l)
    if (length(l) <= 2)
        return(list(l))

    unlist(lapply(2:(length(l)), function(i) {
        left.trees <- trees(l[1:(i-1)])
        right.trees <- trees(l[i:length(l)])
        apply(expand.grid(1:length(left.trees), 1:length(right.trees)), 1, function(idx) {
            list(left.trees[[idx[1]]], right.trees[[idx[2]]])
        })
    }), recursive=FALSE)
}
```

so for the example you gave:

```
> dput(trees(as.list(1:4)))
list(list(1L, list(2L, list(3L, 4L))), list(1L, list(list(2L, 
    3L), 4L)), list(list(1L, 2L), list(3L, 4L)), list(list(1L, 
    list(2L, 3L)), 4L), list(list(list(1L, 2L), 3L), 4L))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a beautiful little solution.